# Could an 150 pound human have flown on the back of some species of pterodactyl (assuming they still existed)?

Tags: ornithology, dinosaurs, flight

I'm curious if any type of flying animal that ever existed would have been able to carry your average 150 pound man.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that the heaviest pterosaurs (Quetzalcoatlus, Hategopteryx) probably weighed around 200 kilograms... No. This extra load would have required a huge amount of extra muscles and the forces acting on the wing bones (which are the distal phalanges of the 4th finger) would be too high.

The biggest bird was Teratornis incredibilis with an estimated weight of around 25 kilograms... This should answer your question.

Comment: I assume you mean biggest *flight capable* bird, given modern ostriches typically reach weights of [over 150kg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_largest_birds) (adult males). In any case, the extinct flighted bird [*Argentavis*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argentavis) is estimated to have weighed in excess of 70kg.

Comment: Thanks for adding this! I'm no native speaker... So sorry for my confusing English. You are totally right with Argentavis but even this bird wouldn't carry a human